# Using Spring Security, what's the right way to manage authorization to query responses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Using Spring Security (v. 3.2.5), what's the right way to manage authorization to query responses?

I have configured Spring Security to regulate access to different parts of the system based on user roles. But in many places, the principal is querying for data (e.g. looking up previously persisted details "owned" by him/her).

The simple use case can be handled simply in code but we have a more complex use case for data retrieval and I'd like a more centralized Authorities Engine and I'm trying to leverage Spring Security for this.

Most examples and online pointers seem to focus on locking down the API calls but not the data generated from those calls.  (User level v. Role level).

Any pointers on how this should be done or tutorials focused on data access at the application layer?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to query a list of items that a user may not be the owner of but should be able to access anyways, yes? Like shared documents or some-such.

If that is the case, you need to upgrade to Spring Security 4 . It allows for SpEL expressions with Spring Data. Example:

```
@Query("select m from Message m where m.to.id = ?#{ principal?.id }")
```

See:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#data

You need to do this in SQL and not with `@PostAuthorize` as pagination will be screwed up with the latter.

If you have the budget though, I'd go with Oracle VPD.

If you can wait til September, Postgres 9.5 will have Row Security.

Some ramblings on sharing here: http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/12/postgresql-row-security-sharing-rls-vpd.html

Comment: Thanks Neil.. This is going to impact my DB design from now on to make sure I account for the ACL's consideration.. Thanks much for the direction!